# Send multiple parameters to msiexec when installing MSP patch?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, msp

I am trying to run an MSP silently and also without rebooting. I have:

msiexec /p "mypatch.msp" /s/v/qn

which basically means run the patch silently / no interaction. The /v I believe is supposed to be the switch to send the 'qn' parameters directly to msiexec. So, in order to tell msiexec to not restart, I would think that saying '/v/norestart' would work, however it does not (the command ends up being invalid and I get the msiexec usage/help dialog)

Is there a way to send multiple parameters to msiexec when installing a patch?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silently and nointeraction is the same thing altho silently not exsist in msiexec options.
/v is not working like you wrote, /qn alone is parameter same as /norestart

`msiexec /p "mypatch.msp" /qn /norestart` stands for patch quietly (non gui output)

More info about msiexec:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: thank you but how are these links supposed to help me understand how to send more than one parameter (such as 'qn' and 'norestart' to msiexec when installing a patch?

Comment: Sorry, it sliped out somehow, edited post:) But If you visit these links, there are examples..

Comment: I see no examples dealing with patches and parameters for them :(

Comment: That line I wrote in my post... ?

Comment: You are correct, I apologize - I am actually asking the wrong question here. New post here if you're interested: http://superuser.com/questions/514957/send-multiple-parameters-to-msiexec-when-installing-exe-patch