# Send multiple parameters to msiexec when installing EXE patch?

Tags: installation

I am trying to run an EXE (Update) silently and also without rebooting. I have:

"myUpdate.EXE" /s/v/qn

which basically means run the patch silently / no interaction. The /v I believe is supposed to be the switch to send the 'qn' parameters directly to msiexec. So, in order to tell msiexec to not restart, I would think that saying '/v/norestart' would work, however it does not (the command ends up being invalid and I get the msiexec usage/help dialog)

Is there a way to send multiple parameters to msiexec when installing an EXE update?

UPDATE: [this](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm) link notes an example of:

```
Setup.exe /s /v"/qn INSTALLDIR=D:\Destination"
```

So framing in context of my own update EXE:

```
MyUpdateEXE /s /v"/qn /norestart"
```

However this is not working - I get the msiexec usage/help dialog as if the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Well, if it's a exe file, then `msiexec` is not a case here, because it's an `msi` installer. You could post exactly what installer it is (In case thats publicly available). Because there is plenty of installer solutions and therefore many possibilities for parameters.

Comment: Generally if you type `yourUpdate.exe /?`, that sometimes can give you a help for given installer. Another thing is, that parameters you type are usualy in windows separated by space like `update.exe /s /v /n`

Comment: @week Its an EXE-wrapped MSP built from InstallShield.

Comment: Try initial space in brackets like `update.exe /s /v" /qn /norestart"`.

Comment: And if that /norestart won't work you may add `REBOOT=ReallySuppress` parameter to msi.

Comment: @week nice work it is update.exe /s /v" /qn /norestart"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Msiexec is really touchy about right parameters alignment.:)

Because InstallShield Setup handover parameters without initial space,

*update.exe /s /v"/qn /norestart"*

have to be formated with space after quotes.

`update.exe /s /v" /qn /norestart"`